# UIBarButtonItem with customView disappears in iOS4.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I'm using a customView for a UIBarButtonItem in my app. This works fine in iOS4.2 (and haven't had any error reports about iOS4.0), but in iOS4.1 applying the customView makes the whole button disappear. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening / what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
//array with button particulars:
// - the UIBarButtonItem to apply
// - image for normal state
// - image for highlighted state
// - button title
// - method to handle the click/tap
NSArray *buttonArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aUIBarButtonItem, @"btn_img.png", @"btn_img_over.png", @"btn_title", @"clickHandler:", nil];

//configure the UIButton to use as customView 
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;     
[button setTitle:[buttonArr objectAtIndex:3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// make the buttons content appear in the top-left
[button setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
[button setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop];

CGSize textSize = [[button.titleLabel text] sizeWithFont:[button.titleLabel font]];
CGFloat labelWidth = textSize.width;

buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[buttonArr objectAtIndex:1]];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[buttonArr objectAtIndex:2]];
[button setImage: buttonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage: buttonImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

[button addTarget:self action:NSSelectorFromString([buttonArr objectAtIndex:4]) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// move text 10 pixels down and right
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50.0, -40.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
[button setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, (labelWidth - buttonImage.size.width)/2 , 0.0 ,0.0)];      

button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, MAX(labelWidth, buttonImage.size.width),  buttonImage.size.height + 20);

//apply customView to UIBarButtonItem
barButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)[buttonArr objectAtIndex:0];          
barButton.customView = button;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for this:

1. Use `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView::(UIView *)customView` instead of assigning the customView to an existing UIBarButtonItem.
2. Add the line `button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);` (haven't tested this myself)